# Hyperledger Fabric: MSP directory to be used while defining docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to deploy a multi-peer architecture using Hyperledger Fabric. I define three peers, manufacturer-peer, customer-peer and regulator-peer. I have generated the crypto materials and they are in the 'crypto-config' folder.
The folder:

> ordererOrganizations
>
> > Orderer-org
> >
> > > ca , msp , orderers , tlsca , users
>
> peerOrganizations
>
> > Customer-org , Manufacturer-org, Regulator-org

All of them have the same folders

> > > ca , msp , peers , tlsca , users

Inside the peers folder, we have regulator-org and in the sub-folder we have another msp folder.

Inside the users folder, we have Admin@Regulator-org and in the sub-folder we have another msp folder.

So basically inside the Regulator-org folder, we have **three msp directories**.

While defining the docker-compose.yaml file, we set environment variables.
We have to define the path to the    ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR and    CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH.

My question is, which msp folder's path do I have to specify for the     ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR and    CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH?

Currently I'm using these paths:

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Regulator-org/users/Admin@Regulator-org/msp

ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=//crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/Orderer-org/orderers/orderer/msp
```

And as a result, i get this error:

[Screenshot of the Docker logs of orderer and regulator-peer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtmjZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the **ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR** to the msp folders in the orderer directory, in your case, link it to ***/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp***

Set the **CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH** to the msp folder in the peer directory which you would like to be the anchor peer. In your case, link it to ***users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp.***

But you have to realize that you need to link the file path in your docker container instead of your host file path.

Comment: I didn't link the host file path to the docker container. Now i've done that in the volumes section of the docker-compose.yaml file.


volumes:
    - /crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/Orderer-org/orderers/orderer/msp:/crypto/orderer/msp

And I've defined the environment path as ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/crypto/orderer/msp

I still get the same error that is in the screenshot.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Well, you have to do the same thing for the anchor peer container that you've chosen. And after you've done it, try to log into your peer container using bash and check if the file path in your error exists in your container. if only directory name occurs but nothing in the folder, you have to use the full file path in your volumes section instead of just relative file path.